# python -(HOMEWORK) need help on my recursive function for a grid

Tags: python, recursion, grid

Ok so I'm writing a program that will run through a grid, and find chambers. For each chamber that is white it fills it with a color. As long as the white space next to this spot is also white it continues to fill with color until the space is walled off. Then it continues its scan till it finds a new chamber of white. here is an example of what the grid would look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGHNg.jpg. Here is the code so far...

```
x = 0
y = 0

if cave[row][col] != AIR:
    return
if cave[row][col] == WATER:
    return

if cave[row][col] == AIR:
    cave[row][col] = WATER
    grid.fill_cell(row, col, color)

if row <= length: #RIGHT
    fill(cave, row+1, col, color)
    x+=1
if col <= length: #DOWN
    fill(cave, row, col+1, color)
    y+=1
if row >= 0: #LEFT
    fill(cave, row-1, col, color)
    x-=1
if col >= 0: #UP
    fill(cave, row, col-1, color)
    y-=1
```

and here is where it gets called

```
for row in range(length) :
    for col in range(length):
        if(cave[row][col]):
            if(cave[row][col]) == AIR:
                color = grid.get_cur_color()
                fill(cave, row, col, color)
                chambers += 1
                grid.get_next_color()
```

The problem I am having is that this only works on very simple caves. When I try to run something that doesn't have walls bordering the outside, I get errors. Can anyone spot where my problem is? This is the example of the more complicated caves and how it should look in the end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMEEE.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are testing `x` and `y` for the boundary conditions when you should be testing `row` and `col` instead

What are `x` and `y` even supposed to do here?

Comment: ok thank you that did help, its filling up a little bit more, but still doesn't work 100% I edited the code to reflect the changes.